# how to add row to a table using ReactJS on button click

Tags: reactjs

I have a table and I want to add a row to it when ADD button is clicked. How can I do that using ReactJS instead of simple JavaScript?

**code:**

```
var RecordsComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>row 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>row 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td}>row 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="addBtn" onClick={addRow}>ADD</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    addRow : function() {
        //how to add row using ReactJS?
    },
});

React.render(<RecordsComponent/>, document.getElementById('display'))
```

Comment: Have the data for the extra rows (or all rows, depending on what you are trying to do) saved in your `state`, then conditionally render the extra rows in your `render` function with something like `this.state.rows.map()`.

Comment: @jlaitio can you please write a sample code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to make your React component have a *state* and render the component accordingly based on that data. Forget the old "DOM modification" paradigm where you are playing directly with HTML elements.

Untested but should carry the idea across:

```
var RecordsComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: {
        return {
          rows: ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3']
        }
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    {rows.map((r) => (
                      <tr>
                          <td>{r}</td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                </table>
                <button id="addBtn" onClick={addRow}>ADD</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    addRow : function() {
        var rows = this.state.rows
        rows.push('new row')
        this.setState({rows: rows})
    },
});

React.render(<RecordsComponent/>, document.getElementById('display'))
```

If you're just starting to learn React with your own test apps I would recommend using the most recent version of React, along with, among a lot of other things, the [React ES6 class definitions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
   var RecordsComponent = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function () {
        return {
          tablerows:[
           {fname:"Tom",lname:"Moody",age:23}
          ]
        };
      },    
  addRow: function() {
      // add new data from here    
      var newdata = {fname:"Tom",lname:"Moody",age:23}    
      //take the existing state and concat the new data and set the state again    
    this.setState({ tablerows: this.state.tablerows.concat(newdata ) });    
  },    
  rows:function(){
      return this.state.tablerows.map(function(row,i){
            return   (<tr key={i}>
                     <td>{row.fname}</td>
                     <td>{row.lname}</td> 
                     <td>{row.age}</td>
                     </tr>);
      });
  },

        render : function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td> row 1 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> row 2 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> row 3 </td>
                        </tr>
                        {this.rows()}
                    </table>
                    <button id= "addBtn" onClick={this.addRow}>ADD</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
    
    React.render(<RecordsComponent/>, document.getElementById('display'))
```

Comment: How would you do this with a constructors state? I'm using spfx (TypeScript/Reactjs) and am struggling to convert either answers to fit my existing code.

Comment: @Tom convert the `getInitialState()` to `constructor(props){super(props); state= {
          tablerows:[
           {fname:"Tom",lname:"Moody",age:23}
          ]
        }}`

Comment: yes I can see how that sets an initial state with "Tom" and "Moody" etc in it, but how would you set fname: and lname: from a function? How would you reference it using this.setState({})?